# when i load session class the page do not load CodeIgniter

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, session

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.1.3 and when i try to load session class the page don't load, and don't show any error either , look what i'm trying to do: ( P.S.: I've set the encryption key already ) ( It is the index of the main controller... )

```
   public function index() {

    $this->load->library('session');

    $this->load->helper('assets_helper');


    $data['assets_url'] = assets_url();

    $this->load->view(domain_template() . '/index', $data);

}
```

If i do like above, the code will no load the page, but if i put like that:

```
    public function index() {

    //$this->load->library('session');

    $this->load->helper('assets_helper');


    $data['assets_url'] = assets_url();

    $this->load->view(domain_template() . '/index', $data);

}
```

It's loaded, why it happen? i cant solve it!!

Comment: Have you tried enabling `display_errors` in `php.ini` or calling `ini_set('display_errors', 'On')` before this line in your file so that PHP will output the error?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure the display_errors is ON. And for have sure, I've putted this command line as you suggest , and it's keep the same behavior.

Comment: No, for being sure you should do something like: `call_undefined_function();` to see if it throws a fatal error.

Comment: What happens when you do `$this->load->library('session'); exit('OK');`

Comment: Could you post your session $config values?

Comment: $this->load->library('session'); exit('OK'); -> Shows OK for the first time, in the next refresh show anything.

Comment: $config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the cookie, is the ci_session cookie being set? What happens if you delete it and refresh the page?

Answer (score 1):

Set your CI environment to DEVELOPMENT to display errors, follow Collins suggestion for enabling error reporting at the configuration level as well. You may also wish to tail your logs. On a LAMP stack it's /var/log/apache2/error_log or /var/log/httpd/error_log. Use tail -f PATH_TO_ERRORLOG and reload the page and see what happens.

Comment: define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development'); already ! and log is empty !

Comment: Throw a try catch in there then
`try {
    $this->load->library('session');
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}`

Answer (score 0):

I allways load session on autoload, but if you want to load on specific controller use:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Perfil extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
}

function index() {

}
```

On MAMP errors are not diplayed by default. you shoud activate.

Comment: I'll try this, but i've tryed also to load at autoload... and does not work, but i will try this way, thank you